How can I get Tensorflow and Keras running in my Python DL Model as needed?
Hey Team, hope you all are doing well! I have been trying to set up a DL model to balance a pole but it is throwing this error each time I try to run it:
/home/nate/Desktop/00_Temp/02_Coding/DeepReinforcementLearningBalanceGame.py/.venv/bin/python /home/nate/Desktop/00_Temp/02_Coding/DeepReinforcementLearningBalanceGame.py/BalancingMl.py
2024-06-29 11:13:59.059897: I tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2024-06-29 11:13:59.101402: I tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2024-06-29 11:13:59.102021: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-06-29 11:13:59.750624: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nate/Desktop/00_Temp/02_Coding/DeepReinforcementLearningBalanceGame.py/BalancingMl.py", line 6, in <module>
    from rl.agents import DQNAgent
  File "/home/nate/Desktop/00_Temp/02_Coding/DeepReinforcementLearningBalanceGame.py/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rl/agents/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .dqn import DQNAgent, NAFAgent, ContinuousDQNAgent
  File "/home/nate/Desktop/00_Temp/02_Coding/DeepReinforcementLearningBalanceGame.py/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rl/agents/dqn.py", line 8, in <module>
    from rl.core import Agent
  File "/home/nate/Desktop/00_Temp/02_Coding/DeepReinforcementLearningBalanceGame.py/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rl/core.py", line 8, in <module>
    from rl.callbacks import (
  File "/home/nate/Desktop/00_Temp/02_Coding/DeepReinforcementLearningBalanceGame.py/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rl/callbacks.py", line 12, in <module>
    from keras.utils.generic_utils import Progbar
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.utils.generic_utils'

1. I already tried to remove and re-install the keras package, tensorflow package and also other
versions of these packages.
2. I also tried to use a different environment and install the packages there too.
Lastly, here is the code I am trying to get running:
import random
import gym
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from rl.agents import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import BoltzmannQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory



env = gym.make("CartPole-v1")

states = env.observation_space.shape[0]
actions = env.action_space.n

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(1, states)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(24, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(24, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(actions, activation="linear"))

agent = DQNAgent(
    model=model,
    memory=SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1),
    policy=BoltzmannQPolicy,
    nb_actions=actions,
    nb_steps_warmup=10,
    target_model_update=0.01
)

agent.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001), metrics=["mae"])
agent.fit(env, nb_steps=100000, visualize=False, verbose=1)

results = agent.test(env, nb_episodes=10, visualize=True)

print(np.mea(results.history["episode_reward"]))

env.close()

# episodes = 10
# for episode in range(1, episodes+1):
#     state = env.reset()
#     done = False
#     score = 0

#     while not done:
#         action = random.choice([0, 1])
#         _, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
#         score += reward
#         env.render()


#     print(f"Episode {episode}, Score: {score}")

# env.close


maybe it needs much older version. Did you check in Google which version has keras.utils.generic_utils?

in question (not in comments) you could add information what versions you use: Tensorflow, Keras, RL, Python.

Hey furas, what do you mean by adding the information of which versions in question?

for example print(tf.__version__, tf.keras.__version__ ). And import sys print( sys.version) for Python version. And do the same for other modules. And results show in question. Sometimes problem may exist only in one version but not exist in other version.

Thank you for your response! I ran it and got this as result:
print(tf.version) => 2.13,
print( sys.version)  => 3.8.10,
print(tf.keras.path) => v2

read my previous comment: "And results show in question". It will be more readable. And more people may see it - so more people may help.

it is strange - as I know currently keras is part of tensorflow but when I run pip freeze then I see keras==2.12.0 as separate module. And I can even run pip install keras. So maybe you have to install it as separate module - pip install keras
